# How to send form data from ionic app to parse.com MBaaS using REST API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I'm extremely new to Ionic/Angular (Started today itself out of necessity),

Taking help of tutorials as well as documentations,

I had been creating a demo/test app that submits data to Parse.com MBaaS service.

But something somewhere is going wrong, clueless on how to go add the three form fields

Details: the App name is TestApp
Class/Table name is data

there are three columns, fname, lname and uname (for firstname lastname and username)

Here's the code I've been following. Any help would be deeply obliged.

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">



<div>
    <div>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
            <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon icon ion-ios7-arrow-back">Back</ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </div>
</div>

    <!-- Center content -->
   <ion-view title="Add Data">
    <ion-content padding="true" scroll="false" class="has-header">
        <div class="spacer" style="height: 100px;"></div>
        <form ng-controller="defaultCtrl">
            <ion-list>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name here" name="fname" ng-model="starter.fname">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <span class="input-label">Last Name</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Surname Here" name="lname" ng-model="starter.lname">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <span class="input-label">Username</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username here" name="uname" ng-model="starter.uname">
                </label>
            </ion-list>
            <button class="button button-calm button-block" type='submit' ng-click="create(starter)">Add data</button>
        </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>




<script type="text/javascript">


angular.module('starter',['ionic']).factory('starter',['$http','PARSE_CREDENTIALS',function($http,PARSE_CREDENTIALS){
    return {
        create:function(data){
            return $http.post('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/data',data,{
                headers:{
                    'X-Parse-Application-Id': PARSE_CREDENTIALS.APP_ID,
                    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':PARSE_CREDENTIALS.REST_API_KEY,
                    'Content-Type':'application/json'
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]).value('PARSE_CREDENTIALS',{
    APP_ID: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    REST_API_KEY:'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
});


angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
.controller("defaultCtrl", function ($scope) {
$scope.starter = {};
 $scope.create=function(){
        starter.create({fname:$scope.starter.fname}).success(function(data){

        });




});

</script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the authentication headers

```
PARSE_HEADER_CREDENTIALS = {
    "x-parse-application-id": "PARSE-APPLICATION-ID",
    "x-parse-rest-api-key": "PARSE-REST-API-KEY"
};
```

code

```
addObject: function (_params) {

    // for POST, we only need to set the authentication header
    var settings = {
        headers: PARSE_HEADER_CREDENTIALS,
    };
    // for POST, we need to specify data to add, AND convert it to 
    // a string before passing it in as seperate parameter data
    var dataObject = {
        "name": _params.name,
        "room": _params.room,
    };

    var dataObjectString = JSON.stringify(dataObject);

    // $http returns a promise, which has a then function
    return $http.post(baseURL + 'classes/stuff', dataObjectString, settings)
        .then(function (response) {
            // In the response resp.data contains the result
            // check the console to see all of the data returned
            console.log('addObject', response);
            return response.data;
        });
},
```

complete example posted in project here:
https://github.com/aaronksaunders/info-rest-api-ionic-sample